# MembershipProvider.GetPassword algorithm

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-membership, dotnetnuke, mcrypt

We are converting an ASP site (using DotNetNuke) to a new PHP site. The only thing we have right now is a full export of the existing database. One of the tables is called "aspnet_Membership" and contains the following fields:

- Password (looks like base64)
- PasswordFormat (always value 2)
- PasswordSalt (looks like base64)
- PasswordQuestion (always empty)
- PasswordAnswer (always empty)

We would like to decode these passwords and hash them to fit our own framework. From what I understand from the .NET documentation these kind of passwords can be decrypted. Is there an algorithm available that can do this or is it more complicated than that? Will it be possible if we create an ASP script on the current server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok thanks to your replies ojb and especially Simon, I was able to retrieve the contents of Web.config so we now have the decryptionKey and validationKey. The encryption method is set to "3DES". Does this ring any bells? I guess it should be possible to decrypt it now with PHP mcrypt but I can't seem to find out the correct parameters.

Comment: Hmmm.... don't know if you can do this with PHP. Using .NET, I think you can reuse the membership provider with the GetPassword method: new  SqlMembershipProvider().GetPassword(username, passwordAnswer);

Comment: @Simon Mourier is correct on all his points.  You need the original machine key, the SqlMembershipProvider.GetPassword method will work, there is also a MembershipUser.GetPassword method that doesn't require the answer param.  Finally I checked one of my databases that I know uses encryption and the PasswordFormat field is 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 2 means "Encrypted", not "Hashed" (see the definition [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershippasswordformat.aspx))

Encrypted means you can actually decrypt it but you will need the machine key stored in configuration files (take a look at the link I sent) of the physical machine where these passwords were created. If you have only a copy of the database, then you can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your value of 2 in PasswordFormat tells us that these passwords are hashed, presumably using SHA1 (you can check this in your web.config). There's no way to reliably get the original password back, sorry.

*edit: unless you're aware of a specific cryptographic weakness in the particular hashing function, of course.

Comment: Wow, yes, actually Simon Mourier (below) is right about 2 meaning "Encrypted", provided you're on .NET 3.5 or later. I can't get Reflector out at the moment to check, but it seems they switched the order of the enumeration between versions.